Is this confounding bias or selection bias or both?
Can confounding and selection bias (biased sampling) be the same?
In epidemiology, selection bias and confounding are often considered as two different biases. I wonder if they can be same in certain scenarios. Here is a simple thought experiment:
Let $Y_0$, $Y_1$ denote the potential outcomes of study subjects. I will decide the treatment status of everyone by comparing their $Y_0$ values with value of a random variable $X$. e.g., If $Y_0$ is larger than $X$, the subject will receive treatment  ($T=1$) and if $Y_0$ is less than $X$，the subject will receive no treatment ($T=0$).
I tried to draw a causal diagram here based on the following structural models
\begin{align*}
T=f_T(Y_0,X)  \because T=I(Y_0 >X)  
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
Y=f_y(Y_0, Y_1, T)=Y_0(1-T)+Y_1T
\end{align*}

So we can see $T \leftarrow Y_0 \rightarrow Y$ is a confounding path. $T \leftarrow X \cdot \cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot Y_0 \rightarrow Y$ is a confounding and selection bias path? The difference observed in $Y$ between $T=1$ and $T=0$ is due to confounding and biased sampling at the same time?

What about this suggests anything to do with sample selection? You never identified the part describing how the sample was selected in a biased way.
